# What are the limitations of Watershed Segmentation Algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I am developing an Android application using Opencv to detect objects from images.

I used Canny edge detector to detect the edges and extract contours, and it's working good so far.

But I need to understand the difference of usage of Canny and Watershed segmentation algorithm.

What's the difference between those two algorithms in terms of performance and accuracy ? Or it just depends on the application ?

And can Watershed works on a generic way? That means can it  detect unknown number objects from an image and detect objects with different colors ?

Comment: Canny is an *edge detection* algorithm, while WST is a *segmentation* algorithm. You can't really compare them in terms of performance since they do 2 completely different things.

Comment: Thank you for your response,but they can serve both for the same thing but I can't seem to find anything to not use this or that and the opposite case.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting T A: "Canny is an edge detection algorithm, while WST is a segmentation algorithm.".

The main limitation of WST in that context is that it depends on the quality of the edge detection.